# On utilise "black" ou "noir" pour une personne?

Tags: adjectifs

J'enseigne dans une école et nous apprenons les descriptions physiques. J'ai entendu beaucoup de Français utiliser "black" pour décrire quelqu'un, mais j'ai aussi entendu dire que certaines personnes n'aimaient pas ça et préféraient "noir". Qu'en pensez-vous ? (Je ne suis pas de langue maternelle française..)

Comment: Toute réponse à cette question est forcément l'expression d'une opinion personnelle, le sujet est controversé mais les personnes concernées préfèrent « noir ». Quelques liens vers la presse pour te faire une idée : France Info : [Je n'aime pas qu'on me dise 'black'" : pourquoi, en France, le mot "noir" reste tabou](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/france/je-n-aime-pas-qu-on-me-dise-black-pourquoi-en-france-le-mot-noir-reste-tabou_4003111.html) ; ...

Comment: RTFB : [Comment nommer les personnes noires dans les médias ?](https://www.rtbf.be/info/inside/detail_comment-nommer-les-personnes-noires-dans-les-medias?id=10527824) ; Slate.fr : [Pour une utilisation décomplexée du mot noir](http://www.slate.fr/story/52115/noir) ;  Juste un titre du Nouvel Obs mais c'est parlant : "[Je suis noire, pas 'black'"](https://www.nouvelobs.com/rue89/nos-vies-intimes/20170828.OBS3873/je-suis-noire-pas-black.html) ; ...

Comment: HUffingtonPost.fr [Jean-Pascal Zadi nous explique pourquoi dire "noir" plutôt que "black" ou "renoi" est important](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/entry/dire-noir-plutot-que-black-ou-renoi-ce-realisateur-nous-explique-pourquoi-cest-important_fr_5efde2c8c5b6ca97091a7230) etc...

Comment: Je pensais que cette question avait été posée, mais je ne la trouve pas.

Comment: @Lambie Le sujet a été abordé lors de [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/42178/358) mais  la question elle-même était un peu différente.

Comment: Voir aussi https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11462/how-to-refer-to-the-races-and-skin-colors-of-people-in-french https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12886/how-racist-is-n%C3%A8gre

Comment: @None Je me rappelle d'avoir posté le même article que toi, Je suis noire, etc. Et d'avoir remarqué que le mot noir est le mot préferé par certains. Je ne trouve plus la question....

Answer (score 0):

Noir est le mot qui était utilisé le plus au XX ieme siècle. ([Noir dans le Dictionnaire de l’Académie Française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9N0525) ) :

> Se dit d’une personne ou d’une population caractérisée notamment par une pigmentation sombre de la peau, par opposition à Blanc et à Jaune (s’est substitué dans l’usage au mot Nègre)

Black est arrivé récemment dans la langue française, d’abord utilisé par les jeunes. (Pas encore officiellement dans la langue française)

Il y a aussi eu le terme « personne de couleur » qui a été utilisé dans le but de ne pas stigmatiser et de rester neutre mais aussi parfois dans le but contraire.

Comment: Cette réponse manque de références et de nuances.

Answer (score 0):

Quand j'étais petit "noir" semblait avoir une conotation raciste.
Black est plus recent et je dirais est arrivé dans les années 2000. Je pense que le terme viens des pays anlo-saxons où il est plus identitaire et positif.
En lisant les articles proposés plus haut, on voit que le langage evolue.

Comment: Et si tu lis ces articles tu verras que les personnes concernés dans leur majorité ne veulent pas qu'on les appelle « black » et préfèrent « noir » qui, d'ailleurs n'a jamais eu de connotation raciste, si tu es sûr de toi il faudrait accompagner ta réponse d'une référence.